# Value of type 'OpaquePointer' has no member 'pointee'

Tags: swift, openssl, swift5

I'm trying to compile yenom/BitcoinKit from GitHub. The issue is in BitcoinKit.Private.swift.

The error is "Value of type 'OpaquePointer' has no member 'pointee'".

The code that causes it (leaving in the commented out part):

```
let privateKeyNum = BN_new()!

// other stuff in the file

// Check for invalid derivation.
//if BN_is_zero(privateKeyNum) {
//    return nil
//}
if privateKeyNum.pointee.top == 0 { // BN_is_zero
    return nil
}
```

Now, looking at COpenSSL for BN_new:

```
public func BN_new() -> OpaquePointer!
```

And finally in Swift, C, OpaquePointer:

```
/// A wrapper around an opaque C pointer.
///
/// Opaque pointers are used to represent C pointers to types that
/// cannot be represented in Swift, such as incomplete struct types.
@frozen public struct OpaquePointer {

    /// Creates an `OpaquePointer` from a given address in memory.
    public init?(bitPattern: Int)

    /// Creates an `OpaquePointer` from a given address in memory.
    public init?(bitPattern: UInt)

    /// Converts a typed `UnsafePointer` to an opaque C pointer.
    public init<T>(_ from: UnsafePointer<T>)

    /// Converts a typed `UnsafePointer` to an opaque C pointer.
    ///
    /// The result is `nil` if `from` is `nil`.
    public init?<T>(_ from: UnsafePointer<T>?)

    /// Converts a typed `UnsafeMutablePointer` to an opaque C pointer.
    public init<T>(_ from: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>)

    /// Converts a typed `UnsafeMutablePointer` to an opaque C pointer.
    ///
    /// The result is `nil` if `from` is `nil`.
    public init?<T>(_ from: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?)

    public init(_ from: UnsafeMutableRawPointer)

    public init?(_ from: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)

    public init(_ from: UnsafeRawPointer)

    public init?(_ from: UnsafeRawPointer?)

    public static func != (lhs: OpaquePointer, rhs: OpaquePointer) -> Bool
}
```